# String keys on Arrays with `for ... in`

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop, iterator

Paradoxically, when running a [`for ... in`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for..in) expression on an [`Array`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html), your iterator is not an int as you'd expect, but rather is coerced as a String.  Allow me to demonstrate...

```
for (var key:int in a) { // 
    trace(getType(item) + " = " + a[key])
}

function getType(value:*):String {
    // Returns the type of object passed to it.
    var msg:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(value);
    if (msg.lastIndexOf("::") != -1) {msg = msg.split("::")[1];}
    return msg;
}
```

Running this, you'll get the compile error

`1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type int.`

You'd think Adobe would be mindful of the return value depending on the source object, but in the API ref, it clearly states...

[**Parameters:** `variableIterant:String`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#for..in)

Well, that's obviously a lie, because otherwise how do we traverse `Dictionary` objects?

```
var a:Array = ["a","b","c"];

var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
dict[a] = true;

for (var key:Object in dict) {
    trace(getType(key)); // traces: "Array"
}
```

Immediately, you should be noticing the discrepancy in the strong datatyping of our `key` variable.  Granted, `Object` is the parent class to `Array`, so it's not going to throw a compile error, but it also wasn't coerced to a String.

Trying this again on our array indices, but this time as an `Object`...

```
for (var key:Object in a) {
    trace(getType(item) + " = " + a[key]) // traces: "int = a, int = b, int = c"
}
```

How is it we're accessing array values with object keys?  *This is not a dictionary*.

I suppose I'm venting to some degree, but am I not correct in believing this to be a bug, and worthwhile reporting to Adobe?

Comment: You haven't provided a link to the API doc your referencing for `variableIterant:String` but, I assume since `Dictionary` is [not primitive](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html) and [does not inherit from](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) `Array` it doesn't "have" to follow the same rules. Admittedly it is confusing, but whats also confusing is that there are about 5 different Array-esque classes anyway and no two act in the same way & have the same functions.

Comment: Actually, I did.  First link `for...in`, but I'll add it again on the quote. Dictionary is used here to demonstrate issues with for loop's iterator, and is not specific to `Object`, `Dictionary`, or even necessarily `Array`.

Comment: My appologises, apparently my link colour is hard to see in a code block, my bad. now that I read that I'm happy to eat humble pie on my whole comment, to be honest. Though reporting it to Adobe will probably result in the issue dropping into the void. I knew the docs were bad in places I didn't realize they were wrong at such a low level that can be easily demonstrated with their own classes :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** let me say that using the *for in* loop allows you to access properties of an object. As array inherits from object you can access array elements in string or integer format, but when using a for in loop the iterator reference is always typed to `String` (as you have discovered).

**These `Object` inherited classes act like hash maps.** Array is different as it can perform these lookups with strings or integers. Dictionary on the other hand can use objects for keys without doing a toString() conversion.

To address the last part of the question asking about why we can use Objects in the array look ups. Well as you know the key, the compiler does coerse_s - converting to string when running the for in loop. `String` inherits from `Object`, in the end there is no difference between the string and object for doing the lookup.

Lastly, you can bypass all of this (and should if you are not needing the strictly typed key for anything) by setting the key to untyped:

```
 for ( var key:* in a ) {
    trace(a[key]);
 }
```

This side steps the compiler conversion to a string and is an optimization. See here for more information: [5x Faster For-In Loops](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2514)

Answer (score 0):

You need a plus symbol

Instead:

```
for (var key:Object in a) {
    trace(getType(item) + " = " a[key]) // traces: "int = a, int = b, int = c"
}
```

Use:

```
for (var key:int in a) { // 
    trace(getType(item) + " = "  +  a[key])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers and integers extend Object. You technically always iterate using an object, but the object in this case happens to be an int. This explains why you are getting "int = a" etc...

What do you expect to happen when you run this code snippet?

```
var myObj:Object = {};
var arr:Array = [1,2,3];
arr["dynamicProp"] = 4;
arr[myObj] = 5;
trace(arr);
trace(arr["dynamicProp"]);
trace(arr[myObj]);
trace("\n");
for(var key:Object in arr){
  trace("arr["+key+"] = "+arr[key]);
}
trace("\n");
for(var i:int=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  trace("arr["+i+"] = "+arr[i]);
}
```

Arrays are still dynamic objects. You can name any properties and use other objects as keys. When you choose to use an integer or number iterator on an Array, you will only iterate through the array elements, and not the dynamic properties. A for..in loop will dig up the elements and other dynamically assigned properties of the object.

Here's the output:

```
1,2,3
4
5

arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3
arr[dynamicProp] = 4
arr[[object Object]] = 5

arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3
```